# Get user facebook login status but don't want the redirect

Tags: php, facebook, api, curl, https

I am building a website that uses the php facebook libraries. At the beginning of every page I am checking to see if the user is logged into facebook or not (or trying to) with the $facebook->getLoginStatusUrl($params) function. The issue I have is that the only real way to check with that function is to have the user redirected to a page based on their statues (by directing them to the url given back by that function). I cant use file_get_contents or cURL because the URL returned by that function uses https. Is their anyway I can get the contents of that URL with a server-side method? Or is the absolute only way to do this with a redirect? I would much prefer not to make this a client side action (via Javascript). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the facebook getUser() function to check if the user is logged and has given permisssions to your web. After that you can use getLoginUrl() or getLogoutUrl() to show the user the right button:

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();    

if (!$user)
{
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'redirect_uri' => REDIRECT_URL,
    'scope' => APP_PERMS,
    'display' => 'page'
  ));

  //do something with $loginUrl, for example:
  echo '<a href="'.$loginUrl.'">Login with facebook</a>';
}
else
{
  //check that this user is still valid
  $realUser = $facebook->api('me');

...
```

You can learn more about this functions in facebook docs:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

Comment: I have tried this, and would use it if it worked for me. For some reason, even when I am logged out of facebook, $facebook->getUser() would still return my facebook ID, making it useless to test if I am logged in or not

Comment: That's true, that's because facebook library check first in cookies and if there is a delay untill this cookies get old. It's much slower, but you can check if the user is connected doing a api call that requires an access token: You can call $facebook->api('/me') for example, besides this gives you more info about the user.

Comment: I have updated my post, you can check the real user after getUser has returned an id, this way the page will respond faster to not logged users.

Comment: I figured out something else for my situation but I think what you said has some validity, lets just go with this one

Answer (score 0):

> Is their anyway I can get the contents of that URL with a server-side method?

That won’t help you, because it’s not your server that the client uses to log in to Facebook, but his browser.

And therefor the check if the user is logged in must happen in their browser – that’s why the browser gets redirected to Facebook, because this is the only way to read the cookies that are set under Facebook’s domain.

> I would much prefer not to make this a client side action (via Javascript).

It already is kind of a client-side action, because of the redirect.

There is absolutely no way to have your server alone figure out if the user is logged in to Facebook in their browser.